# Is there a way to call an API for every day of the Year?

Tags: r

I have a vector of all the days in unix format and I want to use all those values in the vector as the value of my timestamp. I want to do this because I want to call the darksky API for every day of the year in 2016. How would I people able to pass this vector through the get_forecast_for command. The notation for the command is stated below and what I want to change is the value of timestamp =. Sorry that this is quite a basic question, but I have been struggling on it for hours. Thanks for the help !

```
get_forecast_for(latitude = 40.730610, longitude = -73.935242, timestamp = 1451624400, language = "en", exclude = "minutely, currently, daily")
```

Comment: A start would be to generate a list of timestamps then use a for loop to iterate through each one

Comment: Yeah so I have generated a list of timestamps, but I am stuck on how to actually loop through each one

Comment: Try writing it into a for loop and I'll finish it if you get stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
install.packages("taskscheduleR")
```

and then

```
    ## Run every day at the same time on 09:10, starting from tomorrow on
## Mark: change the format of startdate to your locale if needed (e.g. US: %m/%d/%Y)
taskscheduler_create(taskname = "myfancyscriptdaily", rscript = myscript, 
                     schedule = "DAILY", starttime = "09:10", startdate = format(Sys.Date()+1, "%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Comment: Hey Med Sep. Yeah so I am not trying to run this command every day, I just want to run the command for every day for the year 2016.